# "Either a Platonist or an Aristotelian"

Tags: aristotle, plato

In his introduction to "The Pocket Greek Reader," W.H. Auden said: one is born either a Platonist or an Aristotelian. (He immediately qualifies that remark with nods to Hippocrates and Thucydides.)

Not knowing much about philosophy, if forced to come up with a word association, I would say *ideal* for Plato and *logic* for Aristotle.

But these simplistic attributes don't even appear so far apart as (Godel and Cohen not withstanding), logic seems to give a definitive rigor to thought processes that render the results 'ideal.'

So my question is: I would appreciate a brief description of what would put someone in either the Platonic or the Aristotelian camp.

Thanks

Comment: It was probably meant more as a statement about philosophical "temperament" then about whether one literally follows the tenets of either philosophy. For example, an Aristotelian temperament in philosophy might be one that tries to hew as close as possible to some "common-sense" view of reality, focusing more on categorizing and analyzing the world as it appears to us, while a Platonic temperament might be more about postulating some ideal reality perhaps very different from common sense appearances. Also see Porteous' 1934 essay at https://www.jstor.org/stable/700449

Comment: IMO, the dichotomy ideal vs logical is not the "best one" (provided that is quite hard to squeeze them into a pair of words...) [Platonism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/platonism/) is the view that we have direct access to *abstract objects* (forms, numbers,...) while for [Aristolte](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-metaphysics/#SubjMattArisMeta) we need a process of *abstraction* starting form "things better known to us" and arrive ultimately at an understanding of "things better known in themselves" (cause, essence,...)

Comment: Auden did not say this and then qualified it. [He wrote](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Forewords_and_Afterwords/bcKGDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Auden+one+is+born+either+a+Platonist+or+an+Aristotelian&pg=PA5&printsec=frontcover) that others said it, and that they were wrong:"*It has been said that one is born either a Platonist or an Aristotelian; but it seems to me that there are more contrasted and significant divisions than this...*" Plato is stereotyped for holistic speculative outlook whereas Aristotle for disecting empirical one, but others exist and one is not born with them.